# in my if statement my variable isn't found?

Tags: java

in my code in my if statement the Objects.deepEquals it says "cannot find symbol - variable Objects" I have a driver code as well but I do not know if that would help.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help

```
public class RunnyStack <Base>{
 class Run{
    final Base object;
    int length;
    Run next;

    public Run(Base object) {
        this.object = object;
        next = null;
        length = 1;
    }

    public Run(Base object, Run next) { 
        this.object = object;
        this.next = next;
        length = 1;
    }

  

}

Run first;
int countDepth;
int countRun;

public RunnyStack() { 
    first = null;
    countDepth = countRun = 0;
}


public int depth(){ 
    return countDepth;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){ 
    return first == null;
}

public Base peek(){ 
    if (first!=null)
        return first.object;
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}

public void pop(){ 
    if (first!=null) {
        first.length--; 
        countDepth --; 
        if (first.length == 0){ 
            first = first.next; 
            countRun--; 
        }
    }
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException();
}

public void push(Base object){
    if (first == null){
        first = new Run(object); 
        countDepth++;
        countRun++;
    }
    else {
        if (Objects.deepEquals(first.object, object)) 
            first.length++; 
        else {
            first = new Run(object, first); 
            countRun++; 
        }
        countDepth++; 
    }
}

public int runs(){ 
    return countRun;
}
```

}

To post this it is asking me to type more. So this part here is only to fill up space. this text is irrelevant.

Comment: And what is `Objects` supposed to be? I can't see being defined in your posted code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show us your `import`(s), but [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) is not in `java.lang` and it is not imported by default. Add

```
import java.util.Objects;
```

or change

```
if (Objects.deepEquals(first.object, object))
```

to

```
if (java.util.Objects.deepEquals(first.object, object))
```

Also, please use `{}` even when optional.